# How do you debug python code with kubernetes and skaffold?

Tags: python, kubernetes, skaffold

I am currently running a django app under python3 through kubernetes by going through `skaffold dev`. I have hot reload working with the Python source code. Is it currently possible to do interactive debugging with python on kubernetes?

For example,

```
def index(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})
```

Usually, outside a container, hitting the endpoint will drop me in the `(pdb)` shell.

In the current setup, I have set `stdin` and `tty` to `true` in the `Deployment` file. The code does stop at the breakpoint but it doesn't give me access to the `(pdb)` shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `kubectl` command that allows you to [attach](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#attach) to a running container in a pod:

```
kubectl attach <pod-name> -c <container-name> [-n namespace] -i -t

-i  (default:false) Pass stdin to the container
-t  (default:false) Stdin is a TTY
```

It should allow you to interact with the debugger in the container.
Probably you may need to adjust your pod to use a debugger, so the following article might be helpful:

- [How to use PDB inside a docker container.](https://medium.com/@vladyslav.krylasov/how-to-use-pdb-inside-a-docker-container-eeb230de4d11)

There is also [**telepresence**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/local-debugging/) tool that helps you to use different approach of application debugging:

> Using **telepresence** allows you to use custom tools, such as a debugger and IDE, for a local service and provides the service full access to ConfigMap, secrets, and the services running on the remote cluster.
>
> Use the `--swap-deployment` option to swap an existing deployment with the Telepresence proxy. Swapping allows you to run a service locally and connect to the remote Kubernetes cluster. The services in the remote cluster can now access the locally running instance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking into [Rookout](https://www.rookout.com/python_debugging/?utm_source=SO) which allows in-prod live debugging of Python on Kubernetes pods without restarts or redeploys. You lose path-forcing etc but you gain loads of flexibility for effectively simulating breakpoint-type stack traces on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use Skaffold, but you can attach the VSCode debugger to any running Python pod with [an open source project I wrote](https://docs.robusta.dev/master/catalog/actions/python-troubleshooting.html#python-debugger).

There is some setup involved to install it on your cluster, but after installation you can debug any pod with one command:

```sh
robusta playbooks trigger python_debugger name=myapp namespace=default
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [okteto/okteto](https://github.com/okteto/okteto). There's a good [tutorial](https://www.okteto.com/blog/how-to-develop-python-apps-in-kubernetes/) which explains how you can develop and debug directly on Kubernetes.